# Define function argument 2 and leave argument 1 as default

Tags: php

If you have the following function

```
function func1($captainObvious="John",$name){
  return "Hallo my name is ".$captainObvious."<br>Welcome ".$name."!";
}
```

How do you call it with argument 2 without giving an argument 1?
I would like to call it with something like

```
func1(default,"Benny");
```

But I can't seem find that possibility.

Comment: Why don't you just switch the order of the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change `func1`, you will have to use `func1("John", "Benny")`. If you can change it but changing parameter order (the preferred solution!) is out of question because of legacy issues, you could use `null` as default flag:

```
function func1($captainObvious="John", $name){
  if ($captainObvious === null) {
    $captaionObvious = "John";
  }
  return "Hallo my name is ".$captainObvious."<br>Welcome ".$name."!";
}

func1(null,"Benny");
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating your functions you should put the parameters that are required *first*, then put the ones with default values after them. Otherwise you end up in a situation like this where you now have to provide a value for that first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the required variables first.

For example

```
Function func1($captainObvious="John",$name){
    return "Hallo my name is ".$captainObvious."<br>Welcome ".$name."!";
}

Function func2($name, $captainObvious="John"){
    return "Hallo my name is ".$captainObvious."<br>Welcome ".$name."!";
}
```

Then if you call these functions

```
echo(func1('', 'Benny'));
echo(func2('Benny', '');
```

will give for func1

> > Hallo my name is.
> >
> > Welcome Benny!

and for func2

> > Hallo my name is John.
> >
> > Welcome Benny!